# How to create create scalability model for Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

How to check following condition

How many streams can support before noticing `Kafka cluster` degradation and how to scale up the cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will hugely depend on what your application is doing, the throughput, and so on. Some general resources to help you:

- [Elastic Scaling in the Streams API in Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/elastic-scaling-in-kafka-streams/)
- [Kafka Streams Capacity planning and sizing](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html)

Comment: Can we use `APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG` for producers also ? I mean using `application.id` and `group.id` we can make groups for consumers.. same way can we make groups for producers using `application.id` and `group.id` ?

Comment: This is a new question, so please start a new post :)